# Join irreducible elements in DCC lattices

Tags: order-theory

The [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Join-irreducible_element) claims

> In a lattice satisfying the descending chain condition (...) the join-irreducible elements are those which cover precisely one element...

I have been unable to prove this statement, any tips or a complete proof of this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mistake in the article's claim: it should be **ascending** chain condition, not descending *(or alternatively "join-irreducible" and "cover" should be replaced by "meet-irreducible" and "is covered by" respectively)*. For an easy counterexample, consider $\omega+1$ as a lattice; the top element does not cover anything, but is join-irreducible.

With that out of the way, let  me prove the correct claim. Some terminology for readers:

- An element $x$ of a lattice $L$ is **join-irreducible** iff there is some $y<x$ and $x$ is not the join of a finite antichain of size $>1$.
- $x$ is a **cover** of $y$ iff $x>y$ and there is no $z$ with $x>z>y$.

It is easy to see that if $x$ is join-irreducible then $x$ cannot cover more than one element: if $x$ covers both $y$ and $z$, then $x=y\vee z$ but $\{y,z\}$ is a finite antichain with more than one element. (Note that ACC is not used here.)

So we just need to show that if $x$ is join-irreducible and $L$ is ACC then $x$ does cover something. This is quick: if $x$ doesn't cover anything and there is some $y_1<x$ in the first place, then we can recursively build a sequence $y_1<y_2<y_3<...<x$, contradicting ACC. (Having found $y_n$ we must be able to find $y_{n+1}\in (y_n,x)$ since $x$ doesn't cover $y_n$.)